# Google Sign In Users and Firebase: Do I need to provide Google users ability to update their email and passwords?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am posting this here because I could not find the answer in the Firebase docs or here.

I have a web app where a user can sign up/login using a Google Sign-in or password/email. I have a settings page where a user can update their password and email address. But, I am confused about how to handle Google Sign-in accounts.

Do I provide a mechanism for the user to update their Google account password and email or is that handled through a Google portal? Or, do I not provide this functionality on my app for Google users and just put up a message stating that they need to change it at a Google site? Just wondering how this is normally handled with Firebase apps or is this something I do not even have to worry about for Google users on my app. What are my options? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to change password within Firebase Authentication is for users of the Firebase Authentication password provider to change their password.

There is no need (nor even a way) for your app to provide your users a way to update their Google password. The best you can do is direct them the web page for their Google account, where they can manage it.